# spring cloud programmatic metadata generation

Tags: spring-cloud

Is there anyway that I can generate some metadata to add to the service when it registers.

We are moving from Eureka to Consul and I need to add a UUID value to the registered metadata when a service starts.  So that later I can get this metadata value when I retrieve the service instances by name.

Some background: We were using this excellent front end UI from https://github.com/VanRoy/spring-cloud-dashboard.  It is set to use the Eureka model for services in which you have an Application with a name.  Each application will have multiple instances each with an instance id.

So with the eureka model there is a 2 level service description whereas the spring cloud model is a flat one where n instances each of which have a service id.

The flat model won't work with the UI that I referenced above since there is no distinction between application name and instance id which is the spring model these are the same.

So if I generate my own instance id and handle it through metadata then I can preserve some of the behaviour without rewriting the ui.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [documentation on metadata and tags](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-consul/blob/master/docs/src/main/asciidoc/spring-cloud-consul.adoc#metadata-and-consul-tags) in spring cloud consul. Consul doesn't support metadata on service discovery yet, but spring cloud has a metadata abstraction (just a map of strings). In consul tags created with `key=value` style are parsed into that metadata map.

For example in, application.yml:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    consul:
      discovery:
        tags: foo=bar, baz
```

The above configuration will result in a map with foo→bar and baz→baz.

Comment: yes, saw that.  I actually want to inject values via code instead of statically as you have them.  So if there is no way to inject them as part of the registration of the service to consul then I guess that is pretty much the end of my efforts :)  Yes?

Comment: No, there are a number of ways, you create an `EnvironmentPostProcessor` that injects the property, you could also extend `ConsulLifecycle`.

Comment: interesting.  I was just looking at the ConsulLifeccyle code.  So if I extend it I add the metatdat (tags) to consul so that other services can see them at service registration?  I will try it anyway, but just asking for clairification.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Based on Spencer's answer I added an EnvironmentPostProcessor to my code.

It works and I am able to add the metadata tag I want programmatically but it is a complement to the "tags: foo=bar, baz" element so it overrides that one.  I will probably figure a way around it in the next day or so but I thougth I would add what I did for other who look at this answer and say, so what did you do?

first add a class as follows:

```
@Slf4j
public class MetaDataEnvProcessor implements EnvironmentPostProcessor, Ordered {

    // Before ConfigFileApplicationListener
    private int order = ConfigFileApplicationListener.DEFAULT_ORDER - 1;

    private UUID instanceId = UUID.randomUUID();

    @Override
    public int getOrder() {
        return this.order;
    }

    @Override
    public void postProcessEnvironment(ConfigurableEnvironment environment,
                                       SpringApplication application) {

        LinkedHashMap<String, Object> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        map.put("spring.cloud.consul.discovery.tags", "instanceId="+instanceId.toString());
        MapPropertySource propertySource = new MapPropertySource("springCloudConsulTags", map);
        environment.getPropertySources().addLast(propertySource);
    }

}
```

then add a spring.factories in resources/META-INF with eht following line to add this processor

```
org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessor=com.example.consul.MetaDataEnvProcessor
```

This works fine except for the override of what is in your application.yml file for tags

Comment: You could read the value from the `Environment` first and then append your new one so it doesn't overwrite.